# Huobi API returns 0 on swap balance

Tags: huobi

I`m writing a trading bot on golang.
I have an account on HTX Exchange, and have an API key to trade automatically. I transferred 180$ to my futures account to trade.
Trying to get my balance from Huobi futures, but it returns 0 for all tokens.

Base URL:

```
https://api.hbdm.com
```

Tried to use endpoints:

```
/swap-api/v1/swap_account_info
```

and

```
/swap-api/v1/swap_balance_valuation
```

All currencies returns 0. No errors.

My API key was bind to my account, right?
How to retrieve my balance on futures with API?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a balance from futures you have to make a POST request to endpoint:

```
/linear-swap-api/v1/swap_cross_account_info
```

with parameter:

```
margin_account: USDT
```